# file sending through hotspot?

Tags: 13.04, file-sharing, hot-spot

Hi is it possible to send files from my PC to mobile which is connected by Hotspot from my PC.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You can use several internet protocols from scp (sshfs) to ftp to http. IMO ssh (scp or sshfs) is most secure, but https will work as well. You will need to secure the ssh server and forward port 22 on one PC, most likely your PC. What part do you need help with ? Specify which server / protocol you want to use, need help with port forwarding ? etc

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I will do as you suggested , is there any article ?

Comment: For ssh ? and sshfs ? See http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/SSH_overview I made those ssh pages for my LUG. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS. Do you know how to port forward ? If you need a windows client, use putty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can connect your phone to your house wifi (if your pc is also connected to the wifi) and then search google play (im going to assume you are on android) for an app called AIRDROID.

i use it all the time to place songs onto my phone without a cable. it links to a port in your router and hosts like a mini server so technically it should work on any operating system on any browser. just download the app, start it. and type www.web.airdroid.com in you your browser.